# finding order of selected div with .eq

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="MyDiv">

  <div class="MyClass">test1</div>
  <div class="MyClass">test2</div>
  <div class="MyClass">test3</div>
  <div class="MyClass">test4</div>

</div>
```

When I click on a MyClass element, I need to return the element's order in TheIndex

```
$('.MyClass').click (function (){
 var TheIndex = ?
 alert(TheIndex);
});
```

For instance, if the user clicks on test2, it needs to return 2 because it's the second element.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
$('.MyClass').click(
    function(){
        alert($(this).index());
    });
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3yMZX/).

Bearing in mind that JavaScript uses zero-based arrays, so clicking on 'test2' will alert the value of '1', rather than '2'. To amend this, you could simply increment the value by 1:

```
$('.MyClass').click(
    function(){
        alert(($(this).index()) + 1);
    });
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3yMZX/1/).

---

**Reference:**

- [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).